# Xamarin Shell Menuitem Command parameter not picked up

Tags: xamarin.forms, menuitem

I'm trying to navigate to the same one page with different query parameters.

AppShell.XAML:

```
        <MenuItem Text="A"
          Command="{Binding NavCommand}"
          CommandParameter="A"/>
    <MenuItem Text="B"
          Command="{Binding NavCommand}"
          CommandParameter="B"/>
```

Code behind:

```
        public Command NavCommand { get; set; }

    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavCommand = new Command<string>(OnMenuItemClicked);
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ListsPage), typeof(ListsPage));
        BindingContext = this;
    }

    public async void OnMenuItemClicked(string MyQuery)
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(ListsPage)}?{nameof(ListsViewModel.Group)}={MyQuery}");
        Shell.Current.FlyoutIsPresented = false;
    }
```

It works, if I use `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(ListsPage)}?{nameof(ListsViewModel.Group)}={MyQuery}");`, but it makes the page second level and hides the hambugber icon.

If I use`await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(ListsPage)}?{nameof(ListsViewModel.Group)}={MyQuery}");` it goes to the page and hamburger icon still presented, but it's not taking MyQuery value.

I have to navigate to another page, then I can click to the menu item and navigate with given parameter. But after that, it's the same - Query parameter still remain and won't change. Again, have to navigate to another page, then I can click to the menu item and navigate with given parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to receive the passed data via using `QueryProperty` to get the `MyQuery` in next page `ListsPage`, and you should add a default constructor for the `ListsPage` ,for example:

```
[QueryProperty("QueryID", "id")]
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ListsPage : ContentPage
{
  private string _typeId;
  public ListsPage()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new ListsPageViewModel();
  }
  public string QueryID
  {
    get => _typeId;
    set => MyLabel.Text = value;
  }
}
```

For more details, you can check the links below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2018/connect/cross-platform-development-introducing-the-xamarin-forms-shell#navigation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#pass-data

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/main/UserInterface/Xaminals/Xaminals/Views/CatDetailPage.xaml.cs

Comment: Yes, I have a query receiver on the page. The problem looks Menu click doesn't fire at all. I receive the parameter after navigating to another page and then back (using those MenuItems), but all MenuItems pointing at the page which is already open seem to be not active.

Comment: Have you set the breakpoint at the MenuItems method `OnMenuItemClicked` to see if it gets there? Also, you can directly use click method to trigger the event for the menuitem.

Comment: It's not getting there, if page is already open. Seems to be Shell behavior :(.

Comment: I tested it and it did get to the breakpoint. If possible, could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo link?